Alerts for Index Recommendations in Datadog Database Monitoring
I am currently utilizing the Database Monitoring feature within Datadog for SQL Server databases and have found the Index Recommendations to be incredibly helpful for optimizing database performance. However, I would like to automate the process of being notified when new index recommendations are generated.
I known Datadog does not offer a direct feature to create alerts or events when new index recommendations are generated. However, I am exploring potential workarounds to automate notifications upon the arrival of new recommendations.
I am interested in any creative solutions or practices within the Datadog ecosystem that could help me achieve this. Ideally, I would like to avoid manual polling and leverage automation, potentially through the Datadog API, to inform me of new index recommendations.
Does anyone has some idea?
